Singleton Instance Mismatch Between Dependency Injection and Static Accessor
I'm trying to create a Singleton LoggerHelper object and retrieve the same instance using Dependency Injection and a static LoggerHelperAccessor. However, I'm encountering an issue where these two approaches don't seem to return the same instance, as shown by differences in the LogId property.
I've added LogId to LoggerHelper to verify if the same instance is retrieved across both methods.
Here’s my setup:
LoggerHelper Class:
public class LoggerHelper : ISingletonLoggerHelper
{
    public string LogId { get; set; }
}

Interface:
public interface ISingletonLoggerHelper
{
    string LogId { get; set; }
}

Startup.cs:
I register LoggerHelper as a singleton and assign a LogId value (using the static accessor) to use for future checking
services.AddSingleton<ISingletonLoggerHelper, LoggerHelper>();
services.AddScoped<LoggingService>();

using (var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider())
{
    LoggerHelperAccessor.loggerHelper = (LoggerHelper)serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISingletonLoggerHelper>();
    LoggerHelperAccessor.loggerHelper.LogId = "55";
}

Static Accessor:
This static accessor class is used to access the LoggerHelper instance, nothing more.
public static class LoggerHelperAccessor
{
    public static LoggerHelper loggerHelper { get; set; }
}

LoggingService.cs:
In LoggingService, I inject LoggerHelper through Dependency Injection and also access it through the static LoggerHelperAccessor. However, _loggerHelper and _loggerHelper2 do not appear to be the same instance, as _loggerHelper.LogId is null while _loggerHelper2.LogId is 55:
public class LoggingService
{
    private readonly LoggerHelper _loggerHelper;
    private readonly LoggerHelper _loggerHelper2;

    public LoggingService(ISingletonLoggerHelper loggerHelper)
    {
        _loggerHelper = (LoggerHelper)loggerHelper; // LogId = null
        _loggerHelper2 = (LoggerHelper)LoggerHelperAccessor.loggerHelper; // LogId = "55"
    }
}

The problem is that _loggerHelper (injected via Dependency Injection) does not retain the LogId value set in Startup.cs, showing null instead, while _loggerHelper2 (accessed through the static accessor) has the LogId set to "55". Additionally, modifying _loggerHelper2 does not affect _loggerHelper, and vice versa, indicating they may be separate instances.
My Question:
Why is the instance of LoggerHelper injected through Dependency Injection not the same as the one retrieved via the static LoggerHelperAccessor, despite setting it up in Startup.cs? What might be causing this discrepancy in my code?

The problem is here: using (var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider())
See ASP0000: Do not call 'IServiceCollection.BuildServiceProvider' in 'ConfigureServices'.

Rule description
Calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code results in more than one copy of singleton services being created which might result in incorrect application behavior. Consider alternatives such as dependency injecting services as parameters to 'Configure'.


Totally correct, after testing this was absolutely correct answer, Thank you so much
